# need Power Shell Script that should export all site content to csv

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, export

I need a PowerShell script that should extract all of the site contents to a CSV-file. This means Lists, and libraries item collection with sub-folder items. Additionally it should extract the sub-site details as well.

Comment: This would possibly require a longish script which iterates through each site's each library & list and each of their contents and finally combines them to a one file. For what I'm aware of, no such solution exists. While we have many ambitious and exemplary users in here, it's not the most likely case you would receive a solution created from a scratch. Therefore it would be great to see you had tried to create a solution of your own, where did you get and what possible problems you faced.

Comment: I disagree that this would be a long script. Loop through the sites, loop through the lists, loop through the list items. There are one-liners for each of those. Google "PnP PowerShell".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the csom powershell script to export
1. All Sub sites in a single site collection
2. All Lists and libraries in a site
3. all List items from all lists in a site
4. All Library items from all libraries in a site.

You need to use `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll` this references where ever the powershell files.

you can download all 4 powershell files and dlls from this [location](https://ufile.io/ahcc3).
you run one by one in order they will generate all csv files.
Make sure you open each file and provide the Web url, site collection url , user name, password.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Export-SPWeb? This exports all site content, including lists and sub sites, to a file. [Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx) is some info.

Comment: While `Export-SPWeb` does this, I'm afraid its syntax is far from CSV.

Comment: Yea it is. I'm afraid I missed what @Rajendar mean at question.